# What other methods would an attacker use for making an HTTP request that isn't Fetch() or an XHR or using the DOM?

Tags: web-browser, http, javascript, ssrf

We are running user-submitted JavaScript, server-side to be executed within a headless browser that doesn't have a DOM or any child of the `window` or `document` or `location` objects - because these are already removed. Is there a way for plain JavaScript on a fully updated version of WebKit/Chrome can create an HTTP request or otherwise use the network using the API and not the DOM?  The team thought that just taking care of the DOM, fetch(), and XMLHttpRequest() was enough. However, there are other features of the browser that can be used to make requests, for example - the following will trigger an HTTP GET request:

```
const font = new FontFace('http_request', 'url(https://cdn.domain.com/file)');
// wait for font to be loaded
font.load();
```

Is it just these methods described?  Or is there some other underhanded JavaScript that can generate malicious network traffic?

Comment: Another one might be: `var x = document.createElement('img');
x.src = 'http://cdn.domain.com/image';`

Comment: @mti2935 that sends one, but it is a DOM operation, not using the Browser's JS API.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but is there some reason you can't just block the headless browser from making outbound network requests at all, or indeed sandbox it so hard it has no ability to access the network, access unneeded files, access processes, etc.?

Comment: @CBHacking we aren't blocking - we are hooking and then giving selective access.  It is a selective filter, not a wall.

Comment: Hooks can often be undone or spoofed, depending on exactly how they're done, so be careful of that. The way browser sandboxes handle this is that the sandboxed process can't make network calls at all; it instead uses IPC to its broker process to request any network action, and the broker performs the filtering when deciding whether or not to honor the request.

Answer (score 1):

Have you blocked or at least restricted [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)? They already don't have DOM access, but can use fetch and XHR, and have their own root element which is not a Window (so overwriting the members of Window won't help).

You also don't mention [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket), which can be used for some types of SSRF and are available both from normal windows and from web workers.

Did you remove access to the `Document()` constructor, or just to the DOM that normally exists in any window? People may be able to get a clean document, or even window, by abusing constructors.

---

In general, I really can't recommend this approach. API sandboxes are always difficult to get right, and this is especially true of JS and its complicated object model, type system, and ever-expanding standard library. Even if you get it right today, there's no guarantee that an update tomorrow won't introduce a new vector.

Instead, you should sandbox the entire browser process. Don't let it access network connectivity at all unless absolutely necessary, and if it is necessary, severely limit that access to the specific host(s) and port(s) needed. Ideally don't let it open sockets at all. Similarly restrict the file system access. The specifics of how to implement such sandboxing vary from platform to platform, but they all support it (for network access in particular you can also use a software firewall).

Comment: You aren't wrong, but we can't just filter it with a generic sandbox, or more specifically SetcompBPF (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/userspace-api/seccomp_filter.html).   SetcompBPF is what youtube and snap use to prevent ffmpeg from shelling the render cluster...